# Dispatch multiple action and wait completion to send next

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store

I'm returning multiple action from one effect, concatMap send action in order but don't wait for completion to send next action.
loadDetails call a REST service and update store when he receive loadDetailsSuccess

I want to finish loadDetailsAction before calling HttpResultActions.httpRequestUpdateSuccessful().

How can achieve that?
From a different action?

```
@Effect()
  removeLibelle$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(DetailsActions.DELETE_LIBELLE)
    .map(toPayload)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(state => state.tree))
    .switchMap(([payload, tree]) => this.libelleService.deleteItem(payload)
      .concatMap(() => {
        return [
         DetailsActions.clear(), //function dispatch action clear
          DetailsActions.loadDetails({ entity: tree.entity,
            dateSearch: tree.search.dateSearch }), //function dispatch GET
          HttpResultActions.httpRequestUpdateSuccessful() //Dispatch action to show modal success
        ];
      }).catch(error => Observable.of(HttpResultActions.httpRequestError(error))));
```

Answer (score 5):

You are doing too many things in single effect. You can liberally break it into multiple effects . Think it this way.

```
DELETE ---> perform delete ----> DELETE_SUCCESS , DELETE_ERROR

DELETE_SUCCESS ---> clear data ----> DATA_CLEAR_SUCCESS

DATA_CLEAR_SUCCESS ----> load data ----> LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS
```

I did the actions in series . You can perform them in parallell also. May be you want to trigger both clear data and load data immediately , then it looks like this :

```
DELETE ---> perform delete ----> DELETE_SUCCESS , DELETE_ERROR

DELETE_SUCCESS ---> clear data ----> DATA_CLEAR_SUCCESS

DELETE_SUCCESS ----> load data ----> LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS
```

Now you can perform model changes in any of these actions. 
Interesting part is , you may have same model change for get http call or get http call after delete is success. That is the beauty of redux.

Your code looks like this

```
@Effect()
  removeLibelle$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(DetailsActions.DELETE_LIBELLE)
    .map(toPayload)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(state => state.tree))
    .switchMap(([payload, tree]) => 
        this.libelleService.deleteItem(payload)
    )// return DELETE_SUCCESS
    .catch() //return DELETE_FAIL

 @Effect()
  removeLibelleDataClear$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(DetailsActions.DELETE_LIBELLE)
        //perform  DetailsActions.clear(),
        //return DATA_CLEAR_SUCCESS action
        // return DATA_CLEAR_ERROR action 

 // If you want to data load in parallell with clear, 
 // you can listen on delete_success . If you want to do 
 // it after data_clear, then listen on data_clear_success 
 @Effect()
  removeLibelleDataClear$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(DetailsActions.DATA_CLEAR_SUCCESS)
        //perform  
        //DetailsActions.loadDetails({ entity: tree.entity,
        //    dateSearch: tree.search.dateSearch })
        // DATA_LOAD_SUCCESS 
        //catch: DATA_LOAD_ERROR
```

You may wish to immediately notify the user that delete is success. And refresh data . Or you can add different action DELETE_SUCCESS_DATA_LOAD_SUCCESS and inform user that delete is success.

Breaking this way makes testing very very easy, compare this with complex switchmap+concat+three http calls.